# Möbius transform calculation, over an annulus

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I started learning about Möbius transformations in my Complex Analysis textbook. This question appeared as an exercise (no solutions are provided, sadly):

Let's say you have a Möbius transform that maps the annulus $r<|z|<1$ to a region bounded by two circles (for the sake of example take $|z|=1$ and $|z-1/4|=1/4$). Is this enough information to figure out $r$?

**What I've tried:** Trying to figure out what different compositions of Möbius transforms will affect in here. I was thinking taking the inverse somehow would be a good idea but I couldn't find my way around the details of how I'd do this.

I'm stumped, so an explanation of how this is possible would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $r$ is determined by the other doubly-connected region $\Omega$ (even if we do not restrict ourselves to Möbius transformations or to domains bounded by circles). A high-tech explanation involves the concept of *conformal modulus*, see [Conformal maps of doubly connected regions to annuli.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/11239)

Here is a low-tech approach which still does not rely on solving for the Möbius map. Let $L$ be a line of symmetry of $\Omega$; in your example it's the real line. Its image under  a Möbius transformation onto $r<|z|<1$ is a line (or circle) $L'$. Since $L$ is invariant under inversion with respect to either boundary component of $\Omega$, $L'$ must be invariant under inversion in the circle $|z|=1$ and under inversion in $|z|=r$. Since the composition of two latter inversions is the scaling map $z\mapsto r^2z$, it follows that $L'$ is a line through the origin $z=0$. Composition with a rotation ensures that $L'$ is the real line.

Now recall that the [cross-ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio#Transformational_approach) is preserved by Möbius transformations. The line $L$ crosses $\partial \Omega$ at four points: in your example they are $-1,0,1/2,1$. The line $L'$ crosses the boundary of $r<|z|<1$  at the points $-1,-r,r,1$. Therefore, the cross-ratios of these quadruples are equal: 
$$(-1,0;1/2,1)=\frac{-1-1/2}{0-1/2}\cdot\frac{0-1}{-1-1}= \frac32 \tag1$$
must be equal to  $$(-1,-r;r,1)=\frac{-1-r}{-r-r}\cdot\frac{-r-1}{-1-1}=\frac{(1+r)^2}{4r}\tag2$$ 
Hence $r=2-\sqrt{3}$.

*Added*: One can do without the knowledge of cross-ratio. The  Möbius map sending $0,1/2,1$ to $-r,r,1$ is described by the equation
$$\frac{z-1/2}{0-1/2}\cdot\frac{0-1}{z-1} = \frac{w-r}{-r-r}\cdot\frac{-r-1}{w-1}\tag3$$
Since we also want $w=-1$ at $z=-1$, equation (3) yields the equality of (1) and (2). Incidentally, (3) also gives a formula for our Möbius map, should we want to have it.

Comment: I understand the first part of your post but I'm actually not familiar with the concept of cross-ratio (or maybe I am, but under a different name?). Is there a "low-tech" explanation that doesn't assume this concept?

Comment: @awr Regardless of knowing it or not before, my advice is to read about it. Since it is an invariant of the transformations you are studying they will appear and will be useful in many problems.

Comment: @Franklin.vp: Alright, I will. Although I'm curious what the writers of the exercise were expecting given that I wasn't introduced to the concept by the textbook asks it.

Comment: I now realized I might've been introduced to this before, it just wasn't called cross-ratio. Going to look at this answer more attentively now.

Comment: @user85506: I think most everything is clear about the answer, but tonight I thought about it again and realized I have one more question. Let's say we switch the roles, and mark $Q$ as the transformation that moves the annulus to the region bounded by the non-concentric circles. Let $R$ be the real line, then, by symmetrical reasoning, it looks like $Q(R)$ has to be $R$. But, wouldn't the symmetry apply for *every* line passing through the origin? i.e. every line L passing through the origin fulfills T(L)=R? This of course doesn't make sense since Mobius transforms are one-to-one.

Comment: @awr A domain bounded by two non-concentric circles admit an infinite family of *circles* of symmetry. The lines through the origin are mapped into such circles (and one of them gets mapped to a line). Without switching the roles, we conclude that $L'$ is a line  using the fact that the boundary components are *concentric* circles.  I added a more precise  symmetry argument to my answer, taking it from an earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

**First solve this exercise:** Given two non-intersecting circles you can find an inversion that makes them concentric.

*Use for this that if two points are inverse of each other with respect to a circle and some other inversion is applied, then their images remain inverses of each other with respect to the image of the circle.*

This will allow you to make the region in the target an annulus. Then bring it to the origin by a translation, and by a dilation overlap it to the known boundary of the annulus in the source. If they don't completely overlap, invert with center the origin and radious the known boundary of the annulus in the target to exchange the order of the boundary (which one is inside and which one is outside). The radius of the other boundary gives you the value of $r$.

Still, computing the transformation is not the most efficient way if you are interested only in computing $r$.

Comment: That's true, I'm trying to compute $r$ with the transformation "known". Can I still make use of your answer for this?

Comment: In principle yes. But if you are interested in $r$ it is too much work to compute the transformation just to compute $r$.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know any hyperbolic geometry? My first thought with such a question would be to first map the circle of radius $1$ to the vertical line going through the origin and then note that a Möbius transformation which fixes this line is a dilation (ie the original Möbius transformation is conjugate to a dilation). It is then easy to determine what this dilation must be to map the image of the circle of radius $r$ to the image of the corresponding circle of radius $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: This approach sounds cool, but I'm not sure what you mean by mapping the transformation to a vertical line?

Comment: For any circle with center on the real axis there exists a Mobius transformation which maps the circle to a vertical line going through the origin such that the left intersection of the circle with the real line is mapped to infinity, and the right intersection is mapped to $0$ (you will have probably seen this as an exercise to prove yourself or as a proposition in your text). Such a map is also unique if you specify the image of one other point on the circle.

Comment: I should have added that the above Mobius transformation has real coefficients. That is, it fixes the upper half plane.